# Jpa Stackoverflow exception in ManyToOne relation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, h2

I have sections inside which I can have subsections and inside them I can have deeper level of sections and further. Entity:

```java
@Data
@Table(name = "section")
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Section {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column
  private Long id;

  @Column private String title;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
  private Section parent;

  @JsonIgnore
  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "parent")
  private Set<Section> children;

  public Section(Long id, String title, Section parent) {
    this.id = id;
    this.title = title;
    this.parent = parent;
  }
}
```

I save all data in h2 database for testing purposes. Repository class:

```java
@Repository
public interface SectionRepository extends JpaRepository<Section, Long> {
  List<Section> findAllByParentId(Long parentId);
}
```

What I have in h2:

[image]

I want to find only these sections which doesn't have parent(First two which have null in parent_id column). How I'm trying to do it:

```java
Section about = new Section(null, "about", null);
Section production = new Section(null, "production", null);

sectionRepository.save(about);
sectionRepository.save(production);

Section subsectionOne = new Section(null, "subsectionOne", production); // without adding
Section subsectionTwo = new Section(null, "subsectionTwo", production); // these two subsections
                                 sectionRepository.save(subsectionOne); // and saving them to db
                                 sectionRepository.save(subsectionTwo); // I don't receive any error on findAllByParentId(null) method call

sectionRepository.findAllByParentId(null); // action
```

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at org.h2.util.ParserUtil.getSaveTokenType(ParserUtil.java:592) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.read(Parser.java:5092) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readIf(Parser.java:5011) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTerm(Parser.java:4306) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readFactor(Parser.java:3343) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readSum(Parser.java:3330) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readConcat(Parser.java:3305) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readCondition(Parser.java:3108) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readExpression(Parser.java:3059) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectExpressions(Parser.java:2931) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelect(Parser.java:2952) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseQuerySub(Parser.java:2817) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectUnion(Parser.java:2649) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseQuery(Parser.java:2620) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:868) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:843) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:815) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:738) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:657) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:595) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1235) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.<init>(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:76) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:352) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.prepareStatement(ProxyConnection.java:337) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.prepareStatement(HikariProxyConnection.java) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:149) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:176) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:151) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.prepareQueryStatement(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:198) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeQueryStatement(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:162) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:104) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.collection.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.initialize(AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.java:87) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:710) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:76) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:102) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:2163) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$4.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:589) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:264) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:585) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:149) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.hashCode(PersistentSet.java:458) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at lv.sawex.core.sections.Section.hashCode(Section.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at lv.sawex.core.sections.Section.hashCode(Section.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.hash(HashMap.java:339) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:607) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.HashSet.add(HashSet.java:220) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:352) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.endRead(PersistentSet.java:355) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollection(CollectionLoadContext.java:239) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollections(CollectionLoadContext.java:224) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollections(CollectionLoadContext.java:198) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.CollectionReferenceInitializerImpl.endLoading(CollectionReferenceInitializerImpl.java:154) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.finishLoadingCollections(AbstractRowReader.java:260) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.finishUp(AbstractRowReader.java:211) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.ResultSetProcessorImpl.extractResults(ResultSetProcessorImpl.java:96) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:105) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.collection.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.initialize(AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.java:87) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:710) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:76) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:102) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:2163) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$4.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:589) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:264) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:585) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:149) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.hashCode(PersistentSet.java:458) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at lv.sawex.core.sections.Section.hashCode(Section.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at lv.sawex.core.sections.Section.hashCode(Section.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.hash(HashMap.java:339) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:607) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.HashSet.add(HashSet.java:220) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:352) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.endRead(PersistentSet.java:355) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollection(CollectionLoadContext.java:239) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollections(CollectionLoadContext.java:224) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollections(CollectionLoadContext.java:198) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.CollectionReferenceInitializerImpl.endLoading(CollectionReferenceInitializerImpl.java:154) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.finishLoadingCollections(AbstractRowReader.java:260) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.finishUp(AbstractRowReader.java:211) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.ResultSetProcessorImpl.extractResults(ResultSetProcessorImpl.java:96) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:105) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.collection.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.initialize(AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.java:87) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:710) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:76) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:102) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:2163) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$4.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:589) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:264) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:585) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:149) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.hashCode(PersistentSet.java:458) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at lv.sawex.core.sections.Section.hashCode(Section.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at lv.sawex.core.sections.Section.hashCode(Section.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.hash(HashMap.java:339) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:607) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.HashSet.add(HashSet.java:220) ~[na:na]
```

`spring.jpa.show-sql=true` Sql result: last sql query recursively repeats.

```
Hibernate: select section0_.id as id1_1_, section0_.parent_id as parent_i4_1_, section0_.title as title2_1_, section0_.titlelv as titlelv3_1_ from section section0_ left outer join section section1_ on section0_.parent_id=section1_.id where section1_.id is null
Hibernate: select children0_.parent_id as parent_i4_1_0_, children0_.id as id1_1_0_, children0_.id as id1_1_1_, children0_.parent_id as parent_i4_1_1_, children0_.title as title2_1_1_, children0_.titlelv as titlelv3_1_1_ from section children0_ where children0_.parent_id=?
Hibernate: select children0_.parent_id as parent_i4_1_0_, children0_.id as id1_1_0_, children0_.id as id1_1_1_, children0_.parent_id as parent_i4_1_1_, children0_.title as title2_1_1_, children0_.titlelv as titlelv3_1_1_ from section children0_ where children0_.parent_id=?
```

**Where is the problem?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by the stack trace and Lombok annotations used, the problem may be related to recursive invocation of `hashCode()`. Lombok's `@Data` will generate implementations for `equals` and `hashCode` methods, and by default these implementations will use all declared fields, including both `parent` and `children` in your case. This means that trying to calculate hash code for "production" entry will trigger calculations for "subsectionOne"/"subsectionTwo", leading back to "production" via `parent` property.

Excluding the set from `hashCode` implementation via adding `@EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude` to the `children` field should solve the issue

Comment: Yes, thank you. But I did it with overriding `equals` and `hashCode` methods to check only fo `id` field instead of all fields of the class.